# Smallest Number Function

Tags: python, function

Trying to make a simple function that determines the smallest number in a list of numbers. For some reason, it looks like my for loop is only executing once for some reason with this function. What am I missing?

```
def smallestnum(list):
    smallest = None
    for value in list:
        if smallest is None:
            smallest = value
        elif value < smallest : 
            smallest = value 
        return smallest 

mylist = [41, 12, 3, 74, 15]
x = smallestnum(mylist)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `return` statement is in your `for` loop. Remove the last indent of your `return`, and it should work fine.

```
def smallestnum(list):
    smallest = None
    for value in list:
        if smallest is None:
            smallest = value
        elif value < smallest : 
            smallest = value 
    return smallest
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems your `return` statement is within the for loop so it gets executed at the end of the first pass.
Removing the `return` from the for loop will solve your problem.